# Integral of Exponential raised by exponential: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x(1-\exp[\frac{-b}{\sqrt{2\pi}a}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2a^2})]).$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am interested in the following integral

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\left(1-\exp\left[\frac{-b}{\sqrt{2\pi}a}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2a^2}\right)\right]\right).$$

Does anyone know how to solve this integral?

Comment: Interesting. But I doubt that the analytical form exists.

Answer (score 3):

Using the identity $1-e^{-z}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\frac{z^n}{n!}$, the desired integral is $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{I_n}{n!}$ with $$I_n:=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\text{d}x\exp\left[\frac{b^n}{a^n\sqrt{2\pi}^n}\exp\left(-\frac{nx^2}{2a^2}\right)\right]=\frac{b^n}{a^n\sqrt{2\pi}^n}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi a^2}{n}}.$$Define $C:=\sqrt{2\pi a^2},\,q:=\frac{b}{a\sqrt{2\pi}}$, so the desired integral is $$C\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\frac{q^n}{n!\sqrt{n}}.$$I'm not aware of any closed-form expression for this, but it clearly converges.

Comment: No hope for closed-form: $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n-1} q^n}{n!
   \sqrt{n}}=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[-\frac{\text{Li}_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(-\frac{q}{s}\right)}{s}\right](1)=\int_0^{2 \pi }
   -\frac{e^{e^{i x}} \text{Li}_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(-e^{-i x} q\right)}{2 \pi } \, dx=\int_0^{\infty }
   \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{t}}-\frac{e^{-e^{-t} q}}{\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{t}}\right) \, dt$ **:(**